# Segmentation fault while operating on user input string

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

Hi Im new to coding in C and I can't seem to find the problem which causes a segfault after the while loop starts.

```
int main() {
    char option;
    char nickname;

    printf("Welcome to our chat program. Please select mode (Send,Nickname,Exit): ");

    while (gets(option)) {

        if(!strncmp(option, "Exit", 4)) {
            break;
        }

        if(!strncmp(option, "Nickname", 8)){
            set_nickname(nickname);
        }

        if(!strncmp(option, "Send", 4)){
            if(!nickname){
            nickname = "Anonymous";
            printf("Your nickname was set to Anonymous!");
            }
            send_message(nickname);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should compile with some warning flags: `-W -Wall` by example. Then you'll see your errors.

Comment: It looks like you're only holding one char for `option` and `nickname` whilst you're comparing them with multiple character strings. That might be the problem.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). BTW `gets` is *obsolete* and should *never* be used. Use `fgets`, `getline`, `readline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with the code. Let's discuss them one by one.

- First of all, a `char` is not sufficient to hold a *string*, you need either

  - an array
  - a pointer with proper (dynamic) memory allocation.

  Using the first approach, you need to change

  ```
  char option;
  char nickname;
  ```

  to

  ```
  #define SIZ 64

  char option[SIZ] = {0};
  char nicknamep[SIZ] = {0};
  ```
- Then, instead of using `gets()`, you should be using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to avoid the possibility of buffer overflow. Something like

  ```
  fgets(option, SIZ, stdin);
  ```

  will do.
- That said, once `option`  becomes an array, you cannot *assign* to it. You need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the content into the array. For example,

  ```
  strcpy(nickname, "Anonymous");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory allocated for the strings.

You need someting like this:

```
char option[50];
char nickname[50];
```

and use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) here:

```
nickname = "Anonymous";
```

and check the string with [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) for example.

```
if(!nickname){
```

It is also safer to use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) with a length parameter to prevent buffer overflow.

```
while (gets(option)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`option` needs to be `char[???]`

Not sure about nickname but it also needs memory allocated and/or initialisation.  How do you set it? What value do you use?

You'll also need to check for `strlen(nickname)>0` rather than `!nickname` which will test for a null pointer, not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Never *ever* use `gets`; it cannot be used correctly. Instead, use `fgets`, with `stdin` as the third parameter.

You will notice that `fgets` takes the length of the storage you want to assign as its second parameter. The lack of this parameter in the `gets` function is why it cannot be used correctly. You should pass it the value 1 in your case, and pass it the address of your `char` variable. `fgets` will then read one character into your variable.

If you want to read more, you need to start by allocating more storage for the data you'll read. For instance, you could allocate space for 80 characters:

```
char string[80];
```

You can now use `fgets` with `string` as the first character, 80 as the second, and `stdin` as the third. `fgets` will then read up to 80 characters from `stdin`.

If you don't want to store that number in two locations in your source code, you can use the `sizeof` operator instead, or use a macro to predefine the size of your buffer.